# Fragments removed after Activity recreate

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an app, where fragments are changing in the container of one `Activity`. I am using `FragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag)` to switch between fragments.

All fragments has `setRetainInstance(true).` When I press Home button and go back to app everything is ok, but when I turn on developers option **"Don't keep activities"** and do the same, I end up with "**clean**" activity where there is only the first (initial) fragment presents. In other words, after Activity is reinitialised all fragments are lost.
How can I avoid that and save fragments state?

Comment: What's the point of turning on `Don't keep activities` in the Dev-Options? Ever thought that the Fragment state isn't saved because of this?

Comment: The point is to test app's behaviour in different situations. For example when activity was finished by the system while in background.

Comment: Any one any thoughts?

Comment: @ArtyomDeynega Hi, have you solved this?

Comment: Unfortunetelly no :(